# Why don't create 'main.css' file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, webpack

I begin to leart webpack and stack. In code below doesn't create new css file and 'main.css' and i don't understand why. Code ends successfully and jade>html creating.

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main.js",
    output: {
    path: "dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
},

module: {
    loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["es2015"] }
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style','css')
    },
    {
        test: /\.jade$/,
        loader: "jade"
    }]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("main.css"),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/jade/index.jade'
    })
]
};
```

Comment: Does your entry at `"./src/main.js"` contain an import on whatever CSS file you're trying to extract?

Comment: Yes, it contain string: import './css/main.css';

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` and `main.js` files? :)

Comment: Oh guys ,i decided it. My redactor Brackets after assembly display jade>html file and bundle.js, but don't display main.css!!!! I accidentally enter in project folder via file manager and main.css was there. I don't understand it, but be careful.